# dropdown and a checkbox insertion syntax not well done

Tags: php

I'm doing a form: database is as follows, the `country_state_city` table has `countries`, `states` and `cities` that are being currently posted well. being the city in the column city converting to a string.

What i want to do here is `$_POST` the the skills checkbox into a string in the column skills and the values to be separated by a comma. I've been trying always unsuccessful. i would wish to someone help me do this.

```
//database
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `country_state_city` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(250) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `country_state_city_form_data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `city` text NOT NULL,
  `skills` varchar(250) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `country_state_city`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `country_state_city_form_data`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

  ALTER TABLE `country_state_city`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=22;

ALTER TABLE `country_state_city_form_data`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=6;
```

index.php (where the form is located)

```
<?php
//index.php

include('database_connection.php');

$country = '';

$query = "
    SELECT country FROM country_state_city GROUP BY country ORDER BY country ASC
";
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();

foreach($result as $row)
{
    $country .= '<option value="'.$row["country"].'">'.$row["country"].'</option>';
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Insert Dynamic Multi Select Box Data using Jquery Ajax PHP</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.lwMultiSelect.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.lwMultiSelect.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <br /><br />
        <div class="container" style="width:600px;">
            <h2 align="center">Insert Dynamic Multi Select Box Data using Jquery Ajax PHP</h2><br /><br />
            <form method="post" action="insert.php" id="insert_data">
                <select name="country" id="country" class="form-control action">
                    <option value="">Select Country</option>
                    <?php echo $country; ?>
                </select>
                <br />
                <select name="state" id="state" class="form-control action">
                    <option value="">Select State</option>
                </select>
                <br />
                <select name="city" id="city" multiple class="form-control">
                </select>
                <br />
                
                <input type="hidden" name="hidden_city" id="hidden_city" />

                <span>Select languages</span><br/>
                    <input type="checkbox" name='skills[]' value="PHP"> PHP <br/>
                    <input type="checkbox" name='skills[]' value="JavaScript"> JavaScript <br/>
                    <input type="checkbox" name='skills[]' value="jQuery"> jQuery <br/>
                    <input type="checkbox" name='skills[]' value="Angular JS"> Angular JS <br/>
                    <?php
                    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

                    if(!empty($_POST['skills'])) {

                        foreach($_POST['skills'] as $value){
                        echo "value : ".$value.'<br/>';
                    }

                    }

                    }
?>

                <input type="submit" name="insert" id="action" class="btn btn-info" value="Insert" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#city').lwMultiSelect();

    $('.action').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() != '')
        {
            var action = $(this).attr("id");
            var query = $(this).val();
            var result = '';
            if(action == 'country')
            {
                result = 'state';
            }
            else
            {
                result = 'city';
            }
            $.ajax({
                url:'fetch.php',
                method:"POST",
                data:{action:action, query:query},
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('#'+result).html(data);
                    if(result == 'city')
                    {
                        $('#city').data('plugin_lwMultiSelect').updateList();
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    });

    $('#insert_data').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if($('#country').val() == '')
        {
            alert("Please Select Country");
            return false;
        }
        else if($('#state').val() == '')
        {
            alert("Please Select State");
            return false;
        }
        else if($('#city').val() == '')
        {
            alert("Please Select City");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $('#hidden_city').val($('#city').val());
            $('#action').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            var form_data = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url:"insert.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:form_data,
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('#action').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    if(data == 'done')
                    {
                        $('#city').html('');
                        $('#city').data('plugin_lwMultiSelect').updateList();
                        $('#city').data('plugin_lwMultiSelect').removeAll();
                        $('#insert_data')[0].reset();
                        alert('Data Inserted');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

fetch.php (to retrieve the value from the country_state_city table)

```
<?php
//fetch.php

if(isset($_POST['action']))
{
    include('database_connection.php');

    $output = '';

    if($_POST["action"] == 'country')
    {
        $query = "
        SELECT state FROM country_state_city 
        WHERE country = :country 
        GROUP BY state
        ";
        $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute(
            array(
                ':country'      =>  $_POST["query"]
            )
        );
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
        $output .= '<option value="">Select State</option>';
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $output .= '<option value="'.$row["state"].'">'.$row["state"].'</option>';
        }
    }
    if($_POST["action"] == 'state')
    {
        $query = "
        SELECT city FROM country_state_city 
        WHERE state = :state
        ";
        $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute(
            array(
                ':state'        =>  $_POST["query"]
            )
        );
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $output .= '<option value="'.$row["city"].'">'.$row["city"].'</option>';
        }


    }
    echo $output;
}

?>
```

insert.php (where my insertion synthax is wrong and i need help in)

```
<?php
//insert.php

if(isset($_POST['country']))
{
    include('database_connection.php');
    $query = "
    INSERT INTO country_state_city_form_data (country, state, city, skills) 
    VALUES(:country, :state, :city, :skills)
    ";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(
        array(
            ':country'      =>  $_POST['country'],
            ':state'        =>  $_POST['state'],
            ':city'         =>  $_POST['hidden_city'],
            ':skills'           =>  $_POST['skills'],
        )
    );
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();

    if(isset($result))
    {
        echo 'done';
    }

}

?>
```

database_connection.php

```
<?php
//database_connection.php
$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blog2", "root", "");
?>
```

Comment: Storing a comma seperated value into a (RDBMS) database is not the best aproach

Comment: what do you advice me to do ?

Comment: Create a table `skill` and a one-to-many table`skills_per_country_state_city`

Comment: ok thanks for the advice, if i want to include radio buttons as well i should create another table too ?

Comment: No, radio buttons are used when you only want one option to be selected, so it's fine to add a specific field for that value/option to the table